# Air pressure between two objects

Tags: pressure

Lets suppose there are two bodies very close to each other. A book on table. Since they are not perfectly smooth there is air inside between them. How can the air exert 1 atm pressure between the book and table interface.

If two objects are very close to each other why is the atm pressure still same.

Comment: Why do you think the 1 atmosphere pressure outside would not compress the air in the gap to 1 atmosphere when there is no pressure seal between them? This has been explained on your other question https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/637796/room-pressure-and-tiny-gaps

Answer (score 0):

Why would you expect it to be different? The pressure of the air on the book is the result of the averaged impact of the moving molecules that comprise the air. This in turn depends upon the number of molecules striking the book in a given time and their average speed. The gap between the book and the table might seem small from a human perspective, but it will be easily large enough to be occupied by air in which the molecules have the same density and speed as in the surrounding air.

Of course, it is possible to make such close contact between two surfaces that air cannot enter between them. For example, it is common for people to move sheets of glass using suckers, which work because the air pressure between the two surfaces is much reduced.

Comment: Can you give reference for your answer and suggest some sites and books for this phenomenom

Comment: I cannot, Parth, but I am sure you could find several in a few minutes using a search engine.